# Issue in calling the function using ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded()

Tags: javascript

I am facing issue while calling the function using `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded()`
I am writing like:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(PopulateDropDown, "sp.js");
</script>
```

Now my function `PopulateDropDown()` doesn't get executed.

Answer (score 2):

There is a slight difference on how `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` works depending on what page it is being executed on.

Sometimes SP.js is available and other times it is not. When it's not availble, the call to `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` will fail as SP.js is not loaded.

View my answer to a similar question [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/108964/inconsistent-executeordelayuntilscriptloadedfunction-behaviour-in-my-pages) for more on this.

Answer (score 1):

[ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff411788%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

You can try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(myfunction, "sp.js");
});

myfunction = function(){
 /*Do something here.*/
};
```

Or try following the answer found [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/39731/pass-parameters-in-executeordelayuntilscriptloaded-in-javascript-client-object-m):

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () { alertThis("Hello World") }, "core.js");

function alertThis(value)
{
  alert(value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint 2013 prefer [SP.SOD.executeFunc(key, functionName, fn) Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff409592%28v=office.14%29.aspx) instead of [SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(func, depScriptFileName) Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff411788(v=office.14).aspx) to ensure that `sp.js` library is loaded before the specified callback function runs.

**Solution**

Replace:

`ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(PopulateDropDown, "sp.js");`

with

`SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', PopulateDropDown);`